# Creating bulk sync using YAML does not create the schedule time

Tags: palantir-foundry, foundry-data-connection

Ref below YAML config part for schedule time which is 12 minutes past the hour every 8 hours
the bulk syncs get created however the schedule time does not generate.
Using the default bulk sync configuration also yields the same result, the schedule is not getting created.
Is this a config issue or due to the bulk sync being experimental ?

```
schedule:
      type: time
      time:
        time:
          cronExpression: 12 */8 * * *
          timeZone: America/Chicago
```

How can the schedule be added when creating bulk syncs using the YAML config?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The bulk sync creation functionality is behind a feature flag, thus still considered experimental, maybe applying schedules is a known issue due to this. Thus I would recommend reaching out to your internal counterparts or support team.

In its current state Bulk Sync Creation does not support creating schedules.

Comment: thank you for that detailed explanation, i'll reach out to the support team and ask them